# what is the y axis for a bar chart? I just want count

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I just want to make a nice bar chart rather than a histogram.

I have no idea what to put as the Y value for the barchart

```
df.Chequing_Account.value_counts()
```

```
no Chequing account    312
0<=...< 200 EU         220
< 0 EU                 218
>=200                   50
Name: Chequing_Account, dtype: int64
```

```
sns.barplot(data =df, x ='Chequing_Account', y = ?, estimator=sum)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is:

```py
counts = df['Chequing_Account'].value_counts()
sns.barplot(counts.index, counts)
```

Alternatively, you can even just do:

```
sns.countplot(x="Chequing_Account", data=df)
```

Both yield the same result:

[image: Value count bar chart using index]